# JavaScript Match parenthesizes if exist a left or right parenthesize in regular expression

Tags: regex

I have my regular express below, it matches phone number correctly.

```
var reg2= /^(\d?)[-. ]?[(]?(\d{3})[)]?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/g;
```

The problem I'm having is my reg2 return valid for the inputs below.How do I create a regular express that if it detects a parenthesize, it requires another parenthesize to be valid, else return invalid.

```
"555)-555-5555"
"(555-555-5555"
"1 555)555-5555"
```

**Edit**

At the same time it should work with regular

```
15556667777
1-555-666-7777
1 555 666 7777
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex for making sure you match only matching parentheses or no parentheses:

```
/^\d?[-. ]*(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})[- ]*\d{3}[- ]*\d{4}$/
```

`(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})` is alternation to allow `(111)` or `111` at the start of phone number.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ooM5dd/2)

Comment: can I ask you what is the difference between $`(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})` and `(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})`. The obvious difference would be $`?:`. If there isn't a difference, what is $`?:` specifically used for?

Comment: `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group and `(...)` is a capturing group. Using non-capturing group is considered better for overall efficiency.